# Let $S \subset \Bbb R^n$ be non-empty. Prove that $\partial S \neq\varnothing$.

Tags: general-topology

I've been stuck on this one for a while, any help on how to prove this?

Let $S \subset \Bbb R^n$ be non-empty. Prove that $\partial S \neq\varnothing$.

Comment: Hint: first prove it under the assumption that $S$ is not closed. (Also, I changed "6=" into "$\neq$"; you should fix that if you meant something else)

Comment: thank you, then I'm assuming that I prove it under the assumption that S is closed? @EricStucky

Comment: Well, you must also prove it for closed $S$, of course. But there is a trick you can use to reduce the closed case to a non-closed case. So you should focus on the non-closed case first.

Comment: (You also need the assumption that $S\ne\mathbb R^n$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\partial S$ is empty. Then, since $\partial S=(\operatorname{closure}(S))\setminus(\operatorname{interior}(S))$, it follows that $$S=\operatorname{closure}(S)=\operatorname{interior}(S).$$

In particular, $S$ is both open and closed. Since $\mathbb R^n$ is [connected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space), this is possible only if $S=\varnothing$ or $S=\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a consequence of the connectedness of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since if the boundary is empty then $S$ and its complement disconnect $\mathbb{R}^n$.